# Form that has a similar behavior to info.plist that when you click on + sign two fields will appear for the key and value [iOS Swift 5]

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, eureka-forms

I am making an eCommerce app. In the add item viewcontroller, I want to create a form with a section that has dynamic fields that behave like the info.plist that when you click on the + sign 2 fields will appear for the key and value. This is because not all items have different volumes, some products have just 1 volume available. The volume of the product as the key eg. 1 Liter or 2 Liters or 3 Liters etc. and the value would be the corresponding price of the selected volume. I'm trying out Eureka form with their sample codes for MultivaluedSection and still quite confused on how to use it and was only able to manage to add 1 field at a time instead of 2 fields. Any ideas on how to do it? Thank you

```
    MultivaluedSection(multivaluedOptions: [.Reorder, .Insert, .Delete],
                       header: "Multivalued TextField",
                       footer: ".Insert adds a 'Add Item' (Add New Fields) button row as last cell.") {
        $0.addButtonProvider = { section in
            return ButtonRow(){
                $0.title = "Add New Fields"

            }
        }
        $0.multivaluedRowToInsertAt = { index in
            return NameRow() {
                $0.placeholder = "Liters"


            }
        }
        $0.multivaluedRowToInsertAt = { index in
            return NameRow() {
                $0.placeholder = "Price"


            }
        }

        $0 <<< NameRow() {
            $0.placeholder = "Liters"
             print($0.value)
        }
        $0 <<< NameRow() {
            $0.placeholder = "Price"
             print($0.value)
        }

    }
```